# MVC Spring dispatcher and resource files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I have problem with dispatcher of MVC Spring. My project structure like this

```
myproject
    |-- webapp
           |-- themes
                  |-- theme1
                         |-- assets
                               |-- css
                               |-- js
                               |-- img
                               ...
                         |-- views
                  |-- theme2
                         |-- assets
                               |-- css
                               |-- js
                               |-- img
                               ...
                         |-- views
           |-- WEB-INF
```

And my `web.xml` file is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/themes/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I added default mapping for *.css, *.js file but I cant access them. Please help me.

**ADDITION INFO**
I can access these files

```
/myproject/themes/theme2/assets/js/theme.js
/myproject/themes/theme2/assets/js/common.js
/myproject/themes/theme2/assets/js/main.js
```

but not

```
/myproject/themes/theme2/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
/myproject/themes/theme2/assets/css/*.* // cant access any css files
```

Comment: Remove the servlet mapping(s) for `default`  and add `<mvc:default-resource-handler />` to your `DispatcherServlet` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should only configure the 1 Servlet which is the dispatcher. Try using the  tag:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/path/to/your/assets/" />
```

So in your case you will setup up like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/myproject/themes/" />
```

And you will call the assets using the URL:

```
/assets/theme2/assets/js/main.js
/assets/theme2/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. I'm not a genie so I can't tell whats wrong blindly. Where did you add the <mvc:resources> configuration?

Comment: I added it in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. But the problem is theme name. It's dynamic. I cant fix assets path

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use the path. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works on for image file and js files in `js` folder not in `plugins` folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52146/discussion-between-ayman-and-bob-khin)

Comment: Thanks so much. But I resolve this problem by my self. I just deleted the target folder and everything work fine (It's so weird. I dont know why)